# How to prevent images from being printed on a report using DataOnly?

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

We've got an Access report that was likely created back in Access 2002, before we upgraded to Access 2010.

We're programmatically setting the Me.Printer.DataOnly of this report to True or False depending on whether the report is being printed onto pre-printed stationery or plain A4.

It used to work perfectly - images are printed onto plain paper (DataOnly = False) and images are not printed onto pre-printed stationery (DataOnly = True), but since updating the images in Access 2010, the images seem to print no matter what value is assigned to DataOnly.

Is this expected behaviour in Access 2010?  What's the best fix for this?

We've programatically set the visibility of the images in code as a short term work around, but I can't help but feel there's a better fix.

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  Me.imgHeader.Visible = Not Me.Printer.DataOnly
End Sub
```